# PHP object help -> unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR

Tags: php, object, gettype

Please help me understand:

```
print gettype(new CustomerObject())
```

prints: "object" (so it is an object)

BUT

```
print gettype((new CustomerObject())->get_customer());
```

prints: unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR

If I do it over two lines it works fine

```
$object = new Customer($order->customer_id);
print gettype($object);
```

prints: object

```
$customer = $object->get_customer();
print gettype($customer);
```

prints: array

It appears that the lines cannot be joined into a single call.
Is this correct? and what is the logic behind that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are a little confused

```
print gettype((new CustomerObject())->get_customer());
```

Tries to call the method get_customer() on what gettype returns. (A string isn't an object)

Basically, if you want to create an object, and then call a method on it, you have to do it on two separate lines.

This no worky:

```
$array = new Object->getArray();
```

This worky:

```
$object = new Object;
$array = $object->getArray();
```

Comment: Ok, just as I thought... I've dabbled with java and you can call the method as a part of the object declaration... This is obviously a feature that is exclusive to java?

Comment: Well, it isn't exclusive to java. Just excluded from PHP.